# Placeholder in Select that uses Backbone Collection

Tags: backbone.js

I have a select box that gets populated through a Backbone Collection:

```
class Prog.Views.History extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['backbone/templates/shapes/history']
  tagName: "option"


  initialize: ->
    @model.bind('change:formatted', @render, this);

  render: ->
   $(@el).html(@template(history: @model))
   this
```

backbone/templates/shapes/history

```
<option value="<%=history.get('origin')%>"><%=history.get('origin')%></option>
```

This works great, all the correct data is presented in the select box, but what I would like is for the first option to be "please select" i.e. a placeholder... I thought about injecting a record called "placeholder" into the collection but it seems like a round about way.

This is how I call it:

```
  appdenDropdown: (history) ->
    console.log("append trigger")
    view = new Prog.Views.History(model: history)
    $('select#history').append(view.render().el)
```

How can I default this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I don't think this implementation is gona work properly, I think the result of the render will be something like:

```
<option><option value="the_origin">the_origin</option></option>
```

Attention to the *double option*.

A proper solution could be this:

```
class Prog.Views.History extends Backbone.View
  tagName: "option"

  initialize: ->
    @model.bind('change:formatted', @render, this);

  render: ->
    $(@el).attr( "value", this.get( "origin" ) )
    $(@el).html( this.get("origin") )
    this
```

Not need of template here.

About the inclusion of the *"please select" option*.

Include the *"please select" option* element hardcoded directly in your HTML into the *select* element.

Then not use `this.$el.html()` to populate the *select* but `this.$el.append()`, this will respect the actual *default option* and it will add the dynamic elements after it.

#### Updated

For example if your *select element* looks like this:

```
<select id="history"></select>
```

Just make it looks like this:

```
<select id="history">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Please select...</option>
</select>
```

As you are using `append` to add the *dynamic option elements* the *placeholder option element* will remain.

Comment: would you mind updating your example with the added placeholder on the apped?

Comment: To do that I need you to update the question with the code that renders the full _select_ element and is making use of the `Traveltime.Views.History` sub-views to render the _options_ elements. Make a signal in this thread when you are ready.